# What is this ambiguous computational existence in the positive integers?

Tags: analysis, logic, foundations

I'm reading *From Sets and Types to Topology and Analysis: Towards Practicable Foundations for Constructive Mathematics.*

The authors mention Bishop’s *Foundations of Constructive Analysis*:

> The successful formalization of mathematics helped keep mathematics on a wrong course. The
>   fact that space has been arithmetized loses much of its signiﬁcance if space, number, and everything else are ﬁtted into a matrix of idealism where **even the positive integers have an ambiguous computational existence.**

What is this ambiguous computational existence in the positive integers?

Answer (score 2):

In order to explain this it is necessary to understand well the view point of Bishop on mathematics (and philosophy of mathematics) in the context of *construcivism* and *intuitionism*. This is crucial becasue when he is saying *"even the positive integers have an ambiguous computational existence"*, this is meant from that point of view. See for instance [here >>>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionism#Truth_and_proof).

One deeper example of intuitionism in number theory refers for instance to Heyting Arithmetic [see here>>>](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#IntNumTheHeyAri).

But more directed to your question, I think a nice reference I have is the article by Kleene, which is about the interpretation of the intuitionistic number theory [>>> here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2269016?uid=3738984&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102562080327)

You may have also a look through L.E.J. Brouwer's work our lectures, and I think Bishop's words very much lean together with Brouwer for instance if you see [here>>>](http://www.marxists.org/reference/subject/philosophy/works/ne/brouwer.htm) and:

> for the elementary theory of natural numbers, the principle of
>   complete induction and more or less considerable parts of arithmetic
>   and of algebra, exact existence, absolute reliability and
>   non-contradictority were universally acknowledged, independently of
>   language and without proof. As for the continuum, the question of its
>   languageless existence was neglected, its establishment as a set of
>   real numbers with positive measure was attempted by logical means and
>   no proof of its non-contradictory existence appeared. For the whole of
>   mathematics the four principles of classical logic were accepted as
>   means of deducing exact truths.

This should bring you nearer to the *intuitive* mystics behind the sentence of Bishop. *Very roughly* said, by *"ambiguous computational existence"*, Bishop is claiming that the *intuitive* and *constructive*, so called *exact thought processes* are being missed.